# How to I make sure the path in jQuery autocomplete call to CakePHP controller/action resolves correctly?

Tags: php, jquery, linux, cakephp

I have the CakePHP stack in /var/www/site

from one view under controller A I do a jquery ajax call:

```
$("#searchstring").autocomplete("/items/getitemsforautocomplete", {  ... more code
```

when the call is triggered I can see from firebug that cakephp wants to call:

```
http://localhost/items/getitemsforautocomplete?q=me
```

Note that 'site' is missing, resulting in a 404.

When I upload this to my site it works the way it should. How should I configure this correctly??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't '/' go to the root directory of the site?  If your javascript file is in /var/www/site/script, you might want to do:

```
$("#searchstring").autocomplete("../items/getitemsforautocomplete", {  ... more code }
```

Comment: Thanks - that did it (in only 11 min. - love the stack)

Comment: $("#searchstring").autocomplete("<?php echo $this->webroot; ?>items/getitemsforautocomplete", {

-- does it also

Answer (score 0):

Try using FULL_BASE_URL in your JS, like:

```
$("#searchstring").autocomplete("<?= FULL_BASE_URL ?>/items/getitemsforautocomplete", {
```

Not the most elegant way, but it solved some of my headaches in the past.

Comment: This should be right - but it does not work. First anserw does ;-)

Answer (score 0):

this is most likely due to the level of the call made from jquery. is the http://localhost/items/... the correct URL?

a not-used html tag that is really good is setting the base href. then all links and javascript calls are made from this.

```
<base href="http://localhost/site/">
```

then just remove the leading '/' from your script

```
$("#searchstring").autocomplete("items/getitemsforautocomplete", {  ... more code
```

Comment: If I leave out the leading '/' cake will think that it should find the action Items in the current controller (called Shops)  at post 'getitemsforautocomplete' as an argument.
No good - but thanks though

Comment: Depends what you have set the base href. If it is as defined above jquery should call [http:/localhost/site/items/get..]